# SQLSERVER comparar dois grupos de resultados

Tags: sql-server, query

Preciso fazer uma consulta no sql server onde tenho que "ligar" estoques à empresas.

O estoque possui 'n' produtos ligados a ele, e estes produtos tem 1 categoria ligados a ele.

A empresa também tem 'n' categorias ligadas à ela.

Preciso selecionar todos os estoques que tenham ao menos 1 produto que a categoria seja igual à uma das categorias da empresa.

Por exemplo:

**Estoque 1**

```
produto 1 - categoria: pedra
produto 2 - categoria: brita
produto 3 - categoria: areia
```

**Empresa 1**

```
categorias: concreto, pedra, cimento.
```

**Empresa 2**

```
categorias: cimento, tijolo.
```

Neste caso, só a empresa 1 visualizaria o estoque 1, pois uma de suas categorias bate com a categoria de um dos produtos dentro do estoque.

**Tabela Categoria**

```
IDCATEGORIA
NMCATEGORIA
```

**Tabela Estoque**

```
IDESTOQUE
NMESTOQUE
```

**Tabela Produto**

```
IDPRODUTO
IDESTOQUE
NMPRODUTO
IDCATEGORIA
```

**Tabela Empresa**

```
IDEMPRESA
NMEMPRESA
```

**Tabela EmpresaCategoria**

```
IDEMPRESA
IDCATEGORIA
```

Espero ter sido claro.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Diego, sua pergunta está bacana, mas sem sabermos como as tabelas são e os relacionamentos fica um pouco complicado de te montar uma query e te ajudar! tenta colocar as tabelas aqui, pelo menos a parte (que te interessa) . abs.

Comment: Diego as categorias dos produtos nas tabelas `empresa 1` e `empresa 2` possuem o mesmo `codigo` que na tabela estoque?

Comment: Coloque a estrutura das tabelas, para podermos ajudar!

Comment: A categoria é a mesma tabela. Editei a pergunta, caso precise de mais dados é só falar. Pensem em usar o "IN", mas so usei ele até hoje de uma variavel em um grupo, não grupo para grupo.

Comment: Talvez subconsulta possa te ajudar.

Comment: Um DER ajudaria a enxergar os relacionamentos entre as tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode aplicar a cláusula `EXISTS` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM Estoque e
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM empresacategoria ec
                     INNER JOIN produto p ON p.idcategoria = ec.idcategoria
               WHERE ec.idempresa = 1
                 AND p.idestoque = e.idestoque)
```

Comment: Obrigado, nunca havia usado este existe, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Confesso que ainda esta nebuloso o que vc quer, mas talves isso ajude:

```
select T4.NMEMPRESA, T1.NMESTOQUE
from ESTOQUE T1
 inner join PRODUTO T2 on T1.IDESTOQUE = T2.IDESTOQUE
 inner join EMPRESACATEGORIA T3 on T2.IDCATEGORIA = T3.IDCATEGORIA
 inner join EMPRESA T4 on T3.IDEMPRESA = T4.IDEMPRESA
```

Caso falte algo complemente aqui nos comentarios.

Comment: Oque eu preciso é o seguinte, eu tenho uma tela que mostra todos os estoques(não vejo os produtos, só se eu clicar no estoque eu vou pra tela que mostra os produtos do mesmo). Nesta tela (a que mostra os estoques) eu tenho que filtrar de acordo com a empresa que está visualizando, ou seja, se eu estou logado com a empresa 2, eu não conseguiria ver, pois entre as categorias as quais estou ligados, não tem nenhuma categoria igual a uma das categorias dos produtos do estoque 1.

Comment: Replica a estrutura e relacionamentos da tabela neste emulador de bd http://sqlfiddle.com/ e compartilha o link aqui . Assim ficara mais facil entender os relacionamentos  das tabelas

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Anderson, a resposta do Sorak resolveu o problema. Abraços.